# how to disable apache mina default logs

Tags: logging, apache-mina

I am working on an application which uses apache mina to send/receive message.
i am getting apache mina logs on colsole

12:01:29.796 [NioProcessor-2] DEBUG o.a.m.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent - Firing a SESSION_CREATED event for session 1
12:01:29.797 [NioProcessor-2] DEBUG o.a.m.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent - Event SESSION_CREATED has been fired for session 1

how to disable these logs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the Mina logger instance and then disable logging on it. The following should work

```
    Logger minaLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.apache.mina");
    if(minaLogger!=null)
    {
        minaLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With log4j (and slf4j over log4j): you can disable any logs for any specified java package.

You can update your logging configuration inside your *log4j.properties* configuration file with :

```
# log4j: how to control logging at package level
log4j.logger.org.apache.mina=LOG_LEVEL 
# where LOG_LEVEL will be the level you need: OFF, INFO, DEBUG, ERROR
```

Maybe these question is a duplicate of :
[How do you Change a Package's Log Level using Log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725958/how-do-you-change-a-packages-log-level-using-log4j)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this with mina that was integrated with a Spring boot application. Firstly you can use the actuator endpoint to find the logger in question:

```
GET /actuator/loggers
```

Examine the output json for the logger in question then adjust the level in the Spring boot application yaml:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSessionImpl: error
```

In a Docker environment this silenced a 'connection reset be peer' WARN log line that was repeatedly generated by a container port scanner.